# Output website X HTML to console in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

Im in a middle of teaching myself to code so do pardon the ignorance.

So my question is, what do I need to read/learn in order to be able to output the HTML of a particular website (e.g google.com) to console?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean output the html in a console application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Essentially, you create the `HttpWebRequest` and then call the `GetResponse()` method.  You can then read the response stream and output it to your console.

Comment: Why does it say OBSOLETE in the description for HttpWebRequest?

Comment: The constructor has been obsoleted (meaning it may be removed in the future), there's a different way to generate the requests, but I'll leave that to you to figure out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to create a request and output the response to the console.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Create a request for the URL.        
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
            // If required by the server, set the credentials.
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            // Get the response.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine (response.StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
            // Cleanup the streams and the response.
            reader.Close ();
            dataStream.Close ();
            response.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read Darrell's code and learn... not sure what you'll learn other than the fact that many here will do your work for you ;)

Comment: I guess copy-and-paste from MSDN is tough. :)

Comment: Yeah I realised that. Notice I didnt ask anyone to provide the solution but to point me in the right direction to learn this stuff myself! lol

Comment: +1 Lazarus, I was trying specifically not to do his work for him, but give him a little direction so he could learn (at least) how to use the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers allow you to right-click and select "View Source", that's the easiest way to see the HTML.

Comment: Yeah but I want to programmatically extract the html to console as a mini project for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class, particularly the example at the bottom of the MSDN page.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream data = client.OpenRead("www.google.com");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string str = reader.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(str);
```